# Django static files

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

Коллеги, всем привет.

Наступил на следующие грабли.
Натягиваю проект из Django==1.9 на один из коммерческих хостингов, но не подтягивается статика.

Судя по комментариям в интернетах, многозначительно ссылающихся на документацию, для корректной работы apache + mod_wsgi необходимо прописать в конфигурационном файле apache:

```
Alias /static/ /your/path/to/static/files/
```

Доступа к файлам виртуального хоста на данном сервере **нет**, только средствами .htaccess.

В моем случае, error_log пестрит 404 эрором до css/js файлов
Сайт работает, но без оформления.

```
manage.py collectstatic
```

кладет статику в указанную в settings.py директорию

```
/home/u/..../static/
```

Но приложение эти файлы не видит...

Что я делаю не так? Как можно победить?
Где и как  нужно корректно прописать алиас/url для маппига /static/ в полный путь...

.htaccess

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.wsgi/$1 [QSA,PT,L]
```

settings.py - касательно статики

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Где конкретно static лежит-то? Я так понимаю, у вас на хостинге должен быть какой-нибудь public_html или что-то подобное — там static и должен быть, для начала

Comment: @andreymal - не в бровь а в глаз. Спасибо! Да, статика лежала ~/public_html/myproject/static, переложил в ~/public_html/static - заработало.

Comment: Этот путь прописывается в STATIC_ROOT и потом команда collectstatic сама должна скопировать в этот каталог всю статику из вашего django-приложения, если что. Так задумывалось разработчиками по крайней мере